# URL to open new Microsoft Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Is there a URL to open a new Microsoft Word 365 document?

Currently I have to open Microsoft Word 365

https://www.office.com/launch/word?ui=en-US&rs=GB&auth=2

and then click on "New Blank Document"

but I'd like to have a link that creates a new blank document straight away.

Comment: I am on offline word so I would not know online word functioning. But offline word (2016, 2019) has a Menu - File - Options - General - Start-up option "Show Start screen when this application starts" if you untick this, start screen doesn't appear and a blank document opens directly. Find whether online 365 has some option like that.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Did you ever find a solution? Google Docs does this automatically and I can setup shortcuts in Linux to open direct to a new word doc.

Comment: No I didn't find a solution and my new company now uses Google Workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the URL that I was looking for https://www.office.com/launch/word?ui=en-US&rs=GB&auth=2

Comment: It still doesn't do exactly what I want (create a new Word document) but it loads much faster than the generic Office 365 page.

Comment: This is identical to what you wrote in your question???